# Responsive tables css

Tags: css

For my school project i have to make a old CRM responsive. All the tables are now completely responsive but there is a minor problem. This is how it looks currently: https://gyazo.com/d39dfa92f335538b66bdbbf432186a95

The person who i'm making the site for now asked if i could place the table headers next too each of the td. I've tried a couple of things which all failed. So i have no clue what else i could do now.
Here is the css i have used to get the tables responsive

```css
/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 500px) and (max-device-width: 1000px)  {

 /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
 table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
  display: block; 
 }
 
 /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
 thead tr { 
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
 }
 
 tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
 td { 
  /* Behave  like a "row" */
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
  padding-left: 5%; 
 }
 
 td:before { 
  /* Now like a table header */
  position: absolute;
  /* Top/left values mimic padding */
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 45%; 
  padding-right: 10px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
}
```

I used this site for the css code. https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer flexbox to address this issue. I'd like to point out this solution I used before: http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/10/11/responsive-tables-with-flexbox/

And to understand how flexbox works, you should look into this nice little game: http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Keep in mind that flexbox does not work in *all* browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox